# Python inport file with elements as int to list

Tags: python, list, import

I want to read as `int`, is there any pythonic way of doing this?

```
f = open('p059_cipher.txt', 'rU')
holder = list((f.read().replace('"', '').split(',')))

Letters = list() 

for number in holder:
    Letters.append(int(number))
```

Comment: What does the input look like?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to guess from your input, but this might work:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('p059_cipher.txt') as f:
    data = "[" + f.read() + "]"

result = list(map(int, literal_eval(data)))
# The call to list is only necessary if both
#   1. You explicitly need a LIST
#   2. You're running Python3
# If you're in Python2 or you just need to iterate, ignore the list call
```

This should take input like:

```
"1", "2", "3", "4", "12", "1003981890213"
```

and create

```
result == [1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 1003981890213]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
with open('p059_cipher.txt', 'rU') as f:
    numbers = list(map(int, f.read().replace('"','').split(',')))
```

This turns a file consisting of `1,2,"3"` into `[1, 2, 3]` (and saves it as `numbers`).